# Included baggage for long haul flight with Lufthansa

Tags: air-travel, luggage, flight-search-engines, lufthansa, long-haul

I'm searching on Skyscanner for a flight for Cluj-Napoca (CLJ) to Toronto (YYZ) for the dates 29 May 2021 - 19 June 2021.

This is the [result's link](https://www.skyscanner.com/transport/flights/clj/yyz/210529/210619/?adults=1&adultsv2=1&cabinclass=economy&children=0&childrenv2=&currency=EUR&destinationentityid=27536640&inboundaltsenabled=false&infants=0&originentityid=27539829&outboundaltsenabled=false&preferdirects=false&preferflexible=false&ref=home&rtn=1).

I select the cheapest one:

[image]

Then I go to the page of mytrip and I see this:

[image]

The sum was modified from EUR to USD but the value is the same so no problem with that. But when I hover over the baggage icon from the right side it says "Baggage not included".

Clicking on Book button, on the next page I see this:

[image]

**UPDATE**

If I go to their website for [baggage calculator](https://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/baggage-calculator) and select from CLJ to YYZ I get this result:

[image]

So which information is corect?

Comment: Of course they do, but it costs more. Checked baggage, seat reservation, etc. all is extra with Lufthansa these days. Seat reservation can be particularly expensive

Comment: @Hilmar I updated my question with what I've found on their website on baggage calculator where for a flight between the airports I talk about it says that a checked baggage is free and included

Comment: Click on "Economy Class" under "Please select your travel class / your fare" and select Economy Class (Light). And see my comment below

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays even on long-haul flights many airlines have fares with no luggage included. Lufthansa for instance has an "**Economy Light**" fare like this.

Some search engines will allow you to specify if you want only fares which include luggage.

Note also that pricing can be weird. I made a random search on the Lufthansa site, and the "Economy Light" fare (without luggage) turned out to be more expensive than the "Economy Basic" fare with includes luggage:

[image]

If you want the most accurate information, it is usually best to check on the ticketing airline's website directly.

Comment: Be also aware that it is usually cheaper to book the higher class with checked luggage included instead of booking the cheaper class and then add checked luggage later. For your flights, the higher class is 50€ more expensive each way. Adding a piece of checked luggage to the Economy Light fare is for trans-atlantic flights at least 60€.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, @ jcaron, I updated my question with what I've found on their website on baggage calculator where for a flight between the airports I talk about it says that a checked baggage is free and included. Don't know what to believe now

Comment: @LeoMessi The screenshot you added is for "Economy Class". If you click on the "Travel class/fare" select, you'll see there's another "Economy Class (Light)", and when you select that the included checked bag goes away. It's often difficult on reseller sites to find out what sub-type of Economy they are selling. I recommend you search for actual flights/fares on the LH site, you'll get the detail as above.